# Extracting temperatures from a string

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, substring

I am currently trying to extract values from a string. The said string contains REAL temperature values taken from a CPU:

I.E. (Based on a Quad-Core CPU)

```
    40.5 °C 42.4 °C 39.9 °C 40.0 °C
```

(spaces ARE included | Depending on the number of cores, there can be less/more temps)

I am currently trying to take each value from the singular string, then use those values to find an average. While I have been able to find ways to do this, my solutions have been inefficient, containing multiple loops and such.

This function is used to find the ever-updating values of the CPU's temperature, shown on a real-time updating XAML, so the algorithm needs to be as efficient as possible.

If you want to take a crack at finding an efficient algorithm, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: This is a perfect candidate for regular expressions.

Comment: I agree with @Amy

Comment: New to coding. What are regular expressions, and how would they help? Thanks!

Comment: [Online Regex References](http://regexstorm.net/reference) Here is some regex refereneces

Comment: why is it so important that the temperatures are "REAL temperatures"?

Comment: ``System.String.Split()`` is your friend here. Regular expressions appear in this case as if going after a fly with a bazooka. I am sure this small F# snippet is easily translated to C#: ``let parse (s : string) : float[] = 
    s.Split([|" "; "°C" |],System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    |> Array.map float``

Comment: Regular expressions are slow. The OP asked for the most efficient algorithm.

Comment: Are you ultimately interested in the average temperature? Or do you want the individual temperatures for some other reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no answer using the very handy `System.String.Split()` function, yet - here is one:

```
double[] Parse(string s)
{
    var valueStrings = s.Split(new string[] { " ", "°C" }, 
        System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return valueStrings.Select(xs => System.Double.Parse(xs)).ToArray();
}
```

Theoretically a hand knitted implementation might be faster, since technically, this solution iterates over the string, then iterates over the result of the splitting again. Those two steps could be done with only one iteration. But since the number of cores you have will be limited (I have 6 cores, some have 32 or 64 cores - but only few have more), the performance of the code above should be sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

This is a perfect candidate for regular expressions (abbreviated "regex").

```
var input = "40.5 °C 42.4 °C 39.9 °C 40.0 °C ";
var regex = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}\.\d");
var matches = regex.Matches(input);

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Okay, what is this doing?

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}\.\d");
```

This sets up a new regex with a specific format.  In this case, we want to match:

- `\d{1,2}`: `{1,2}` means to match the preceding token 1-2 times.  I am assuming your temperatures range from 0.0 to 99.0.  If this range is exceeded, this line will need to be modified.  You can change the range to `\d{1,3}` to allow a third digit, or `\d+` to allow one or more consecutive digits.
- `\.`: a period - the period must be escaped because periods have special meaning in regex
- `\d`: 1 digit

The third line gets all of the matching sub-expressions out of the input string.  The rest of the code spits the results to your Debug window for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Almost perfect, only this won't work for 3-digit temperatures. Yes it's probably unlikely a CPU temp will go up above 100C, but you don't really want to rely on that.

Comment: @Sach Indeed, I made an assumption that might not be valid.  OP can increase it to 3, or make it boundless by removing the upper bound.  I will note this in my answer.

Comment: Great. Yeah I think boundless is the best option.

Comment: @Amy Thanks for your suggestion! My concern is, if I make it boundless, is it going to search for previous numbers, or take in other characters or spaces? If so, I know I can fix that, however, it just would make the code a bit slower.

Comment: @user9622460 No, boundless means the digits must be consecutive, e.g `\d+` will match one or more consecutive digits, and it will match as many as possible (it's "greedy").  In other words, the input `12345` will have one match, and the input `12 345` will have two matches.  `\d` matches *only* the decimal numbers, and nothing else (spaces fall into this category).

Comment: Awesome, great solution! @Amy

Answer (score 1):

as Amy said in the comments, this problem can be solved easily using Regex.
If you want to learn more about regex, I advise to look at this: https://regexr.com/
If you wanna test your regexs, I advise you to use: https://regex101.com

Anyway, to solve your problem, we'll use regex to capture the number (40.5, 42.4, etc) as a group, following the °C as a literal:
`([0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?) °C` ([try it](https://regex101.com/r/ADYV98/1/)).

The `[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?` captures almost all possible decimal numbers, so it should cover all possible temperatures.

This will give you the number as a group which you could then use however you want. In a C# environement:

```
string str = "40.5 °C 42.4 °C 39.9 °C 40.0 °C ";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str, @"([0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?) °C"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is regex solution :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication55
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "40.5 °C 42.4 °C 39.9 °C 40.0 °C";
            string pattern = "(?'temp'[^ ]+) °C";

            decimal[] temperatures = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => decimal.Parse(x.Groups["temp"].Value)).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

The OP clarified his requirements to allow for single-digit temperatures. Here you go.

```
string temps = "1.1 °C 40.5 °C 42.4 °C 39.9 °C 40.0 °C 4.0 °C 11.1 °C";
decimal sum = 0m;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < temps.Length; i += temps[i + 4] == ' ' ? 8 : 7)
{
    string t = temps.Substring(i, 4).TrimEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(t);
    sum += Decimal.Parse(t);
    count++;
}
decimal avg = sum / count;
Console.WriteLine("Avg = " + avg.ToString());
```

This should be far more efficient than a regex-based solution.

This works by grabbing 4 characters from the string, converting to a decimal, then adding it to the sum. Then, based on whether the fourth character is a space or not, it jumps ahead either 7 or 8 characters to find the next temperature.

An algorithm like this is very fast because it does the minimum amount of work to do the job.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The point is speed, not flexibility. And a 3-digit celsius temperature for a CPU? Not likely.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but let me guess. Try this with a temp of 5.9C.

Comment: Nowhere in the question does the OP ask how to calculate the average.  You are also making an assumption that every temperature will be 4 characters long.

Comment: "I am currently trying to take each value from the singular string, then use those values to find an average"

Comment: @Dan OP did not ask how to calculate the average.  He asked how to extract the temperatures.

Comment: All of the temperatures in the example are 4 characters long. I'm following the example given, which is entirely reasonable given the use case described. I find it hard to imagine a CPU temperature reading below 10 degrees or above 100 degrees.

Comment: Well but as a programmer would you really code a solution this dependent on input being in a specific format?

Comment: Yes, you should when the point is to make the algorithm as fast as possible. The OP explicitly stated that they wanted to prioritize speed over other concerns.

Comment: @Dan would you mind walking through how this works? I am lost on the purpose of parts such as "i +=8", and how parsing by the decimal works. 

Also, 10 C (50 Fahrenheit) SHOULD be considered as a valid temperature. That's not an unlikely CPU temp at all.

Comment: @user9622460 Modified my solution to meet your change in requirements and added some high-level code explanation. Run some benchmarks and I'm sure this will be faster than the accepted answer.